# Disable touchpad right click physical button

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, right-click

When I click on my touchpad's bottom right it acts like a right click. I would like to make it act like a left click. So both "physical" buttons act like left click.

There is an option on Control Panel do "Switch buttons" that enables the right click as the left, but as name the says, it swaps the left button too. So the capability to change the right click seems to be there, but I couldn't find a way to map both buttons to the same button.

I will continue to use my touch gestures to make the right click action by tapping with two fingers. I only want to disable the "physical" click on the bottom right corner.

I'm on a Dell XPS 13 2020.

Comment: Check the synaptics tab in mouse properties, see if there is a setting in there.

Comment: Exactly which XPS model is it? Trying to find the specific touchpad model.

Comment: XPS 13 2020. There is no synaptics tab in mouse properties